How to pass id into a modal using $dispatch
I want to pass the id to my modal and save the id as the application id in my controller and save it to DB. But I can't access the id.
Here is my button in applications.blade:
<a href="#" class="block px-5 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100" 
x-on:click="$dispatch('open-modal', 'bspms-attachments')">Attach
</a>

Here is my form in toggle-button
<div id="uploadModal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close" id="closeModal1">&times;</span>
        <h2>Upload File</h2>
        <form action="{{ route('file.upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <input type="file" name="fileInput1">
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>      
    </div>
</div>

this toggle-button is the content of my modal which is called in my modals.blade:
    <x-pop-up name="bspms-attachments" :show="false" focusable class="w-[650px]"> 
        {{-- Define the width for the modal. The minimum width is 500px --}}
        <x-slot:title>
            Documents/Attachments
        </x-slot:title>
        
        {{-- Content starts here --}}
        <x-toggle-button></x-toggle-button>
    </x-pop-up>

and here is my controller that saves it to database:
ApplicationsAttachment::create([
 'application_id' => ,
 'file_name' => $fileInputName,
 'file_type' => explode('/', $originalFile->getMimeType())[1],
 'file_path' => $filePath,
 'file_size' => $originalFile->getMaxFilesize(),
]);

I can't even verify if I can retrieve the id in my modal because I can't even show it in my console.

By "But I can't access the id." you mean you can't access it on server-side or client-side?

Modify the button in your applications.blade.php like this
<a href="#" class="block px-5 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100" 
   x-on:click="$dispatch('open-modal', {id: {{ $application->id }}, modal: 'bspms-attachments'})">
   Attach
</a>

This will send the ID when the modal is triggered.
